# Fb login session with heroku multiple dynos failed

Tags: php, facebook, heroku

My app is using Facebook login, it works perfectly fine with 1 dyno. But when I increase the number of dyno, the app often forget that I have already logged in. I suspect that the dynos doesn't recognize my session from other dynos.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use some sort of shared session storage like memcached or DB sessions storage. The default disk storage does not scale to multiple dynos.